# Как считать данные, отправленные с клиента на сервер POST запросом с помощью node js?

Tags: ajax, node.js

Помогите, пожалуйста: отправляю с клиента данные и вывожу их консоль - выводит `undefined`. В чем проблема?

ajax запрос клента:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:8080/data/delete/",
  data: {'user_id': 4)
  });
}
```

серверная часть:

```
app.post('/data/delete/', function(req, res) {
  var answer = JSON.stringify(req.body);
  console.log(answer);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Сам решил проблему. Достаточно просто установить bodyParser.